# Using colour schemes with vim and putty

Tags: vim, centos, colors, putty

I am trying to use the desert color scheme with VIM 7.0 on CentOS 5.6 x64 located here:

> http://hans.fugal.net/vim/colors/desert.vim

I've downloaded the file and saved it in my `~/.vim/colors` directory. I then tell VIM to use the colour scheme by issuing:

```
:colors desert
```

It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

However I get this:

[image]

I'm logging onto this server just as a regular user (not `root` or `sudo`) using PuTTY 0.60 and have set the following options under `Window -> Colours`:

```
Allow terminal to specify ANSI colours - checked
Allow terminal to use 256-colour mode - checked
Bolded test is a different colour - checked
Attempt to use logical palettes - unchecked
Use system colours - unchecked
```

If I `sudo` or logon as `root` and try the same I don't get any colours at all other than white text on a black background.

Are these schemes mostly aimed at gVIM and is PuTTY just not able to display these colours?

I've google'd around a bit and bumped into articles such as [this one](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_vim_color_schemes_with_Putty) but they don't appear to work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, PuTTY presents itself as `xterm`. The *terminfo* database, used by various programs to determine the terminal capabilities, says `xterm` supports eight colors only:

```
$ infocmp -1L xterm | grep max_colors
```

This means that even if your version of Xterm *does* support 256-color mode, programs won't know about it.

- The easiest fix is to set your $TERM environment variable to **`xterm-256color`**.

  (In your ~/.profile, you could use:
  `if [ "$TERM" = xterm ]; then TERM=xterm-256color; fi`)
- You can tell PuTTY to *always* identify itself as `xterm-256color`, via *Configuration → Connection → Data → Terminal-type string*.

  Note: If you use #1 or #2, and you connect to a server which doesn't *have* the apropriate terminfo entry, all TUI programs will break.
- You can also set the `'t_Co'` option in vim to `256` to override the terminfo value.

  ```
  if &term == "xterm"
      set t_Co=256
  endif
  ```
- Or you could edit the *terminfo* database.

  ```
  $ infocmp -L -1 xterm | sed -r 's/(max_colors)#[0-9]+/\1#256/' > /tmp/xterm
  $ tic /tmp/xterm
  ```

  The updated entry will be kept in `~/.terminfo`.

Comment: Excellent answer. It's better, but I have feeling 256 colours isn't enough to render these pastel shades. Any idea why I don't get any colours at all when logged in as `root`?

Comment: @Kev: 1) 256-color mode is the best you can get on a VT100-compatible terminal emulator. (I heard KDE Konsole having true-color support, but it's very much nonstandard.) 2) When you log in as root, you get a separate home directory, and a separate `~/.vim/colors` as well.

Comment: I have the color scheme in `~/.vim/colors` but it seems to be ignored. I know vim can see it because if I do `:colors` for a scheme that isn't there it reports `E185: Cannot find color scheme blahblahblah` whereas no error when I do `:colors desert`.

Comment: @Kev: Hm. Do you have syntax highlighting enabled? (`:syn on`) How about $TERM - is it set to a sane value?

Comment: Hmm...colours and syntax highlighting work with `vim` launched as `root` but not `vi`. I can live with that I guess.

Comment: @Kev: Because `vi` *does not have* color schemes or syntax highlighting - or anything except the original basic features. (Vim *is* "Vi Improved" after all.)

Comment: `vi --version` says it's vim, so is it a cut back vim to make it look like vi? Sorry if that's a daft question, it's been years since I worked with unix in anger (SCO Unix boxes with serial ports) and there was only vi (real vi).

Comment: Sort of. When you run vim as "`vi`", it starts in a "compatibility" mode, behaving as much as possible like vi. I don't know CentOS, so I'm not sure if it is just a mode, or an entirely separate trimmed-down build. (My distro packages the real vi instead...)

Comment: Thanks! I did have the right env variable but only after changing putty configuration, it worked